# How to define that a variable may not be present in data class (JSON/Kotlin)?

Tags: json, kotlin, nullable

I have a data class and an object in **Kotlin**:

A **data class** *Tranche.kt*

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Tranche(
        @JsonProperty("id") var id: String,
        @JsonProperty("status") var status: String,
        @JsonProperty("instrumentType") var instrumentType: String,
        @JsonProperty("ssdRepaymentDetails") var ssdRepaymentDetails: RepaymentDetails?,
        @JsonProperty("loanRepaymentDetails") var loanRepaymentDetails: RepaymentDetails?
) : PayloadContent
```

And an **object** in *DummyTransaction.kt*

```
val trancheDummy = Tranche(id = "0", name = "dummy", status = "DRAFT", instrumentType = "Loan", ssdRepaymentDetails = repaymentDetailsDummy, loanRepaymentDetails = repaymentDetailsDummy)
```

Setting RepaymentDetails as nullable I allow the ssdDetails and loanDetails to be null. That's all good, but I don't need both ssdDetails and loanDetails. I need ssdDetails in case instrumentType is SSD and loanDetails in case instrumentType is Loan.

How do I do that, without keeping two data classes for different products? Meaning, I would liek to have the following two objects:

```
val trancheDummySsd = Tranche(id = "0", name = "dummy", status = "DRAFT", instrumentType = "SSD", ssdRepaymentDetails = repaymentDetailsDummy)
val trancheDummyLoan = Tranche(id = "0", name = "dummy", status = "DRAFT", instrumentType = "Loan", loanRepaymentDetails = repaymentDetailsDummy)
```

The need comes from the fact that JSON strings are different for SSD and Loan, while in the back end, where reading it, I only need one attribute (payCycle) from that string, and that attribute is common to both products.

*RepaymentDetails.kt*

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class RepaymentDetails(
        @JsonProperty("payCycle") var payCycle: String?
)
```

This part is written in Go and it defines JSON structure:

```
type RepaymentDetails struct {
    PayCycle string `json:"payCycle,omitempty"` 
}

type LoanRepaymentDetails struct {
    RepaymentDetails // inherits RepaymentDetails struct 
}

type SsdRepaymentDetails struct {
    RepaymentDetails // inherits RepaymentDetails struct 
    LastPaymentDate string `json:"lastPaymentDate,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Is it known ahead of time what type of object is expected or is it determined at runtime?

Comment: It's known at compile time.

Comment: Regardless of device type the details class has the exact same implementation?

Comment: @ryfterek, I updated the question, adding info that you proposed.

Comment: This is unrelated specifically to your question, but you can omit the String in `@JsonProperty` if the String and property name are the same. `@JsonProperty(“id”) var id: String` would become `@JsonProperty var id: String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the class definition of the data object does not change regardless of the data type variable, using a single`"repaymentDetails"` Json attribute of type `RepaymentDetails` annotated with `@JsonAlias("ssdRepaymentDetails", "loanRepaymentDetails")` would be sufficient to deserialise either of the possible payloads into a single, not-nullable field.

As the OP highlights, additional `@JsonProperty("repaymentDetails")` might be necessary.

Comment: It worked, but with a small adjustment. In Kotlin curly braces are redundant, should be  @JsonAlias("ssdRepaymentDetails", "loanRepaymentDetails") var repaymentDetails: RepaymentDetails?, also I needed to add @JsonProperty("repaymentDetails") . This is how it looks like in the end: @JsonProperty("repaymentDetails") @JsonAlias("ssdRepaymentDetails", "loanRepaymentDetails") var repaymentDetails: RepaymentDetails?

Comment: Ah yes, didn't quite get the Kotlin "grammar" right from the top of my head, sorry. I'll now edit the original answer to reflect your correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best thing to do here would be to use a `sealed class` (annotations removed for brevity):

```
sealed class Tranche(var id: String, var status: String, var instrumentType: String) {
    data class SSDTranche(id: String, status: String, var ssdDetails: RepaymentDetails) : Tranche(id, status, "SSD")
    data class LoanTranche(id: String, status: String, var loanDetails: RepaymentDetails) : Tranche(id, status, "Loan")
}
```

But if you really don't want to use two different types, you could at least use an `init` block to validate that you get the right arguments:

```
init {
    when (instrumentType) {
        "SSD" -> requireNotNull(ssdDetails)
        "Loan" -> requireNotNull(loanDetails)
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the sealed class idea, but I don't want to copy/paste my whole Tranche class (in reality there are mamy more attributes than just id, status, instrumentType and details). Where would you place the init block, must it be in every class where I use the Tranche object or do you have an idea how it could be done only once?

Comment: It would go in the body of the `Tranche` class

Comment: Instead of making Tranche a sealed class, I would make RepaymentDetails sealed class that has your SSDRepaymentDetails and LoanRepaymentDetails information with the Tranche data class specifying `var repaymentDetails: RepaymentDetails`. The downside is that you have to create your own serializer and deserializer for the Tranche data class, but it shouldn’t be very difficult to do that.